# "Failed to mount the azure file share. Your clouddrive won't be avaible"

Tags: web-services, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azureportal, azure-cloud-shell

Whenever I start the Azure Cloud Shell, I get this error:

Failed to mount the azure file share. Your clouddrive won't be avaible
Your Cloud Shell session will be ephemeral so no files or system changes will persist beyond your current session.

Can someone help me or explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone help me or explain why this is happening?

By chance did you delete the storage resource that was created for you when first launching Cloud Shell?

Please follow those steps:

1.Run "clouddrive unmount"
2.Restart Cloud Shell via restart icon or exit and relaunch
3.You should be prompted with the storage creation dialog again.

Here [a similar case](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure/Azure-Cloud-Shell-error/td-p/70846) about you, please refer to it.

Also we can delete this cloud shell (in resource group), then re-create it.

Comment: Does that work for you? if you need more help, please feel free to let me know:)

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I was prompted to create the clouddrive after launching the cloud shell for the first time. The resource group and storage account were created but the file share was not. I manually created it and restarted cloud shell with no issues.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case, and the solution was rather trivial.

Cloud shell couldn't access my file share due to misconfigured security settings. I did tweak the new Azure Storage firewall settings without realizing the impact on Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, closing and reopening the Azure CLI worked fine.